# Fixing Android NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-spinner

i am creating an android app right, but  every time I try to run it, I get a NullPointerException at line 2. What could be causing this? I for sure have the spinner in my build.xml file. When you call an object like this is it not getting initialized?

```
public void onStart(){

    spnLocale = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1); //1

    spnLocale.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnSelectListener()); //2

}
public static class MainSectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public MainSectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==1){
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.browse_layout,
                container, false);
            Spinner spnLocale = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);


            spnLocale.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnSelectListener());
            return rootView;

        }

        else {//if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 3){
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                    container, false);
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText("help screen");
            return rootView;

        }

    }
}
```

Here is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/state_array"
        android:prompt="@string/state_prompt" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my log :

```
03-22 03:40:17.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2101): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
03-22 03:40:17.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2101): at com.XXXX.list.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:175)
03-22 03:40:17.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2101): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
03-22 03:40:17.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2101): at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
03-22 03:40:17.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2101): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168) –
```

Comment: Are you sure you reference your correct layout in `onCreate` method? `setContentView(R.layout.build);`?

Comment: 03-22 03:40:17.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2101): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 03:40:17.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):  at com.XXXX.list.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:175)
03-22 03:40:17.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
03-22 03:40:17.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
03-22 03:40:17.242: E/AndroidRuntime(2101):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)

Comment: @user3016349 what is line 175?

Comment: @Raghunandan line 175 is the line i labeled as //2

Comment: @cosmincalistru I have swipe tabs. And build is one of the tabs. I tried changing the content view like you said got the same error anyways.

Comment: Show your whole activity code.

Comment: put your line     spnLocale = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1); in onCreate and check that you have set correct layout in setContentVew(R.layout.yourxml.xml);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was I was using swipe Tabs, so I had to use rootView.findViewbyId() instead of just findviewbyID

Answer (score 0):

If you say `NullPointerException` @ line 2 ie `spnLocale.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnSelectListener());` then `spnLocale` is null.

You might have referenced the wrong layout. ie the layout you have set to the activity does not have the spinner with the id mentioned.

Edit:

```
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.build,
            container, false);
            spnLocale = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        return rootView;
```

Comment: How do i change what layout I am referencing?

Comment: @user3016349 which ever layout that you set to the activity must have a spinner with the id `spinner1`. post the activity code full

Comment: I was hoping this would work! but it says, "cannot make static reference to non-static field spnLocale". But if i change spnlocale to static it says it cant call nonStatic method findviewbyId

Comment: @user3016349 why is it static. You need to post the entire code or forget help

Comment: @user3016349 you have a static inner class. Move it to different .java class and remove static

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Adapter to spinner before you can use onItemSelected Listener... this might help you

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();

String str[]={"Dummy","Dummy","Dummy"};
            spnLocale = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1); //1

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,str);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            spnLocale.setAdapter(adapter);
spnLocale.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }
});

    }
```

Comment: Spinner1 is initialized in the xml file with entries layed out in the strings.xml file. How do i set up the  adapter without getting rid of the data already in spinner1.?

Comment: @user3016349 spinner is not initialized in xml. Its a ui element. You initialize the spinner in activity.

Comment: Alright, I tried that, but not i am getting the same error except for at this point:

        spnLocale.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: @user3016349 if you have the elements like `android:entried=@array/elements` there is no need for adapter

Comment: @Raghunandan I do have the elements like that.

Comment: @user3016349 adapter has nothing to with NPE. Your problem is initialization of spinner. `findViewById` can't find the spinner in the current view hierarch

Comment: @Raghunandan I rather not post all my code, It has sensitive details. but i will try to explain it to as best as possible. I have activity_main and build layouts. I have a view pager and swipe tabs. When on tab1 the build.xml file is being displayed. in oncreate() setcontentview(activity_main) is called. The spinner1 is within build.xml file.

Comment: @user3016349 if spinner is in `build.xml` and you have `setcontentview(R.layout.activity_main)` then you are looking for spinner in the wrong layout. spinner does not belong to `activity_main.xml`

Comment: Raghunandan, I understand what you are saying, but then, How do I fix this? Also, I added more code to the original question

Comment: @user3016349 see the edit in my post. Look for a view in the current view hierachy

Comment: put code from onStart into onCreateView before return statement and do spnLocale = (Spinner)rootview.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

Comment: @Raghunandan Im sorry :(. i dont know why its static. i added the rest of the class to my question.

Comment: I found the problem. All i had to do was change onStart() to onActivityCreated().